# Decorator plugin in SonarQube

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, decorator

We have implemented a SonarQube-plugin with an extension that implements Decorator and deployed it to extensions/plugins.
Unfortunately, when triggering the sonar-analysis, the extension implementation is not called. Is there anything more that needs to be configured?

The implementation looks as simple as this:

```
public class MyPlugin extends SonarPlugin {

    @Override
    public List getExtensions() {
        return Arrays.asList(MyExt.class);
    }
}

@DependsUpon(DecoratorBarriers.ISSUES_TRACKED)
public class MyExt implements Decorator, BatchComponent {

    @Override
    public void decorate(Resource resource, DecoratorContext decoratorContext) {

        Project project = decoratorContext.getProject();

        Measure measure = new Measure();
        measure.setData("abc");
        decoratorContext.saveMeasure(measure);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldExecuteOnProject(Project project) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide details about your environment when asking questions (versions, OSs, logs, steps to reproduce, ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQ 5.2, [`Decorator`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/Decorator.java) does not work anymore. You have to move to the [`MeasureComputer`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/ce/measure/MeasureComputer.java) interface instead.

The API is really unclear about this, and the `@Deprecated` annotation is misused IMHO (usually you first deprecate code, keep it working until it does not work anymore, then you just delete it... you don't deprecate code in order to inform people that it's not usable anymore...)

I guess that somebody at SonarSource forgot what [code deprecation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) is about...

> While a deprecated software feature remains in the software, its use may raise warning messages recommending alternative practices; deprecated status may also indicate the feature will be removed in the future. Features are deprecated rather than immediately removed, to provide backward compatibility and give programmers time to bring affected code into compliance with the new standard.

Comment: Agreed! We currently try to migrate our plugins from 4.5.1 to 5.2 and ran right into the "deprecated" Decorator...